# TXSDateTime - unexpected results = C++ Builder 2007

Tags: delphi, c++builder, c++builder-2007

Here's some code:

```
WideString dt = L"2019-04-06T11:08:19.578+01:00";
TXSDateTime * utc = new TXSDateTime();

utc->XSToNative(dt);

ShowMessage(utc->AsDateTime.DateTimeString());
ShowMessage(utc->AsUTCDateTime.DateTimeString());
ShowMessage(String(utc->HourOffset));
```

I would expect the lines ...AsDateTime and ...AsUTCDateTime to return differing results. But they dont. In both cases, the result is:

06/04/2019 10:08:19

The HourOffset is 1, so should not the AsUTCDateTime return 11:08:19 as the time portion? Or am I misunderstanding how these functions work?

Comment: Maybe the time zone is not set correctly?

Comment: What language is this code in? Please clarify your tags.

Answer (score 1):

Reading through `XBUtils.pas`, there are 2 functions:

`function TXSBaseCustomDateTime.GetAsDateTime: TDateTime;` (Line 1448)

`function TXSBaseCustomDateTime.GetAsUTCDateTime: TDateTime;` (Line 1478)

The UTC version takes the date string and adjusts it by 1 hour.

The non-UTC version takes the date in the string and adjusts it BOTH by the time offset in the string AND the local computer's timezone offset from UTC.

As I'm in London, that local offset is currently 0 and so, by coincidence, the results of the two functions are identical. If daylight savings were active, then the non-UTC version would adjust for that and it would give a different result.

Comment: Good find about the local timezone offset being 0 right now!